# How to Dispose resources in this condition

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have a class like this.

```
Class {

  DataTable GetDetails(){

    DataTable dt = new DataTable;

    try{
        dt = // assigning records here.
        return dt;
    }
    catch{
    }
    finally{
    }

  }
}
```

And this method is used in other classes.
In this Scenario how to implement IDispose and will it give produce any good impact ?

I am new to C# and i just read about disposing and not able to make myself clear in that
in implementing in my situation.

How to free this DataTable ?

Comment: If you are returning the data table then you should `Dispose` it in the calling code, not in this method.

Comment: If the class returns a DataTable it should not be responsible for disposing the DataTable, the consumer of the class should be. Otherwise you could end up with a situation where the class you posted disposes of the DataTable while the class that received it is still using it.

Comment: DataTable does not have anything to dispose.  It merely inherited the method from its base class.  Which doesn't do anything.  Don't bother.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your reply. My Doubt is Since i am passing some what huge data , is it good to dispose or not ?
Since i am new got stuck in understanding it..

Comment: @shan All of the data in `DataTable` is managed, not unmanaged, so there is no need to dispose of it, and disposing of it does nothing.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think this is a good reason for this particular case - `dt` *must not* be disposed because it is returned as result of the method, not because it is pointless.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i also trying to ask that only whether in caller if need to dispose means how do i do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to implement IDisposable for this class. IDisposable is only for *unmanaged* resources: things like Sockets, File Handles, GDI resources, database connections, and delegate subscriptions. That class uses none of these.

> My doubt is since I am passing somewhat huge data, is it good to dispose or not?

Passing around huge data is irrelevant: that's still memory, and memory is a *managed* resource. Again, IDisposable is only for unmanaged resources.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. So in this scenario that is not required right ?

Comment: That's right. IDisposable serves no purpose here at all.

Answer (score -1):

You are returning DataTable type instance so it has to be Disposed or freed in the classes / instances where it is consumed. Or change the pattern and return something that is extracted from DataTable instance and dispose the datatable in finally / catch.

Comment: I think this is much better reason not to have any `.Dispose` calls in the sample - class and method don't *own* any disposable object and hence nothing to dispose. It is up to caller to decide how to deal with returned `DataTable` (where one can follow Hans Passant/Servy's advice to do nothing).